How do we read file which is part of node_modules in component in angular 11?
I have a requirement where I need to calculate md5 checkdum for a file which is part of node_modules folder. I am trying to fetch that file in app.component.ts.
But I am getting file not found error, even though I am giving correct path.
Can anyone please tell how to solve this issue?
below is code snippet:
 async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {

   const filePath = '../../../../node_modules/@xyz/abc-module/lib/test.js';

   fetch(filePath)
  .then((file) => {
    console.log("File:", file);
    file.arrayBuffer();
  });

}

How is that supposed to work? httpclient sends a http request to the backend. And there you most certainly don't have your fontends folder structure anymore but just the packaged we app (at least it will be this way in a productive environment). If you need that md5 in your frontend you need to include a custom build process in your build chain or make sure the file is packed with your app

This seems like an XY problem. What is the actual issue you are trying to solve?

@derpirscher :  Even if i dont use HTTP client, and simply trying to fetch file from node_modules, it is not happeneing..i want to calculate md5 checksum of a package inside node_modules

The is no node_modules in the final package ... If you want to calculate the md5 for some package (for whatever reasons) you have to do it at build time

Create a file inside the src folder with the below contents
checksum.ts
export const ValidChecksum = true;

Write a node.js script that runs when you run build
node validateChecksum.js && npm run build

The script will update the file, checksum.ts which will contain the Boolean that says whether the checksum is valid or not.
Then finally in your code import the const ValidChecksum and check the whatever you want with it

HI, thanks for your reply..but I don't want to calculate checksum for all the packages residing in node_modules. I want to calculate for two specific library..and i am not able to access those files in component.ts.  So I wanted to know how to fetch files which are residing in node_modules

@ShubhangiGarg YOU CAN'T! It's just not possible, because in the packaged version of your angular app there is no node_modules any more. It's just a single JS file where everything that is needed is included (in a probably minimized form) The only way to get the md5 of a file from node_modules is to do it at build time ... Or you can serve those files separately. But then there is no guarantee whatsoever, that the separately served file is the same that was used to build your package

@ShubhangiGarg when you deploy the code the node modules gets optimised and minified and merged to main.js, so it's not possible through angular, you can do this as a separate script and access the output through my method provided, else you need to put your source code in the assets folder which I advice against, try this method, its not in any way lacking , its just preprocessed, you need to access the exact file through node fs I have not shared any node.js code since it's outside the scope of the question

makes sense.. looks like i need to write code inside my build script
